# MySQL: Trying to Create a Trigger Where Another Table is Updated

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger whereby an insertion on one table updates another. This is my SQL Query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER makePayment AFTER INSERT ON Payments FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
      UPDATE Invoice
        SET InvoiceClientPaid = SUM(InvoiceClientPaid + NEW.PaymentAmt)
        WHERE InvoiceID = NEW.PaymentInvoiceID;

END;
```

No matter what I do I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

I don't think it's related to the SUM, because trying a basic = 1 on the SET command gives me the exact error. There is no '' at line 6 which is very confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're entering this query directly into MySQL you will need to change the delimiter prior to the query using (e.g.) `DELIMITER //`, otherwise it thinks the query ends at the `;` at the end of your `UPDATE` statement. MySQL then sees an `END` with nothing before it and complains about the nothing (`''`). So try this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER makePayment AFTER INSERT ON Payments FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
      UPDATE Invoice
        SET InvoiceClientPaid = SUM(InvoiceClientPaid + NEW.PaymentAmt)
        WHERE InvoiceID = NEW.PaymentInvoiceID;

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If I try and use a delimiter I get the following error

`Error Code: 1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)` I'm using Google Cloud SQL and so therefore apparently the Super privilege does not exist.

Comment: This [article](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/troubleshooting-guide/mysql/import/binary-logging) has an explanation of how to resolve that